# Как настроить Bridge для сетевого интерфейса?

Tags: xen, сеть, centos

Есть удалённый сервер с чистой CentOS. Пытаюсь установить на нём Xen по [этой инструкции](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-xen-on-centos-6.3-x86_64-paravirtualization-and-hardware-virtualization).

Серверу выделено 5 ip: `108.170.5.50—54` Хочу сделать так, чтобы виртуальные боксы выходили в сеть как `.54`

**Правильно ли** пытаться сделать Bridge'ем лишь один из 5 IP завязанных на сетевой интерфейс, или же надо весь интерфейс делать бриджем, и лишь затем биндить уже на бридж все 5 ip?

Ниже привёл конфиги чистого сервера сразу после установки CentOS.

**Вывод ifconfig:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:67:D0:D2            inet addr:172.24.159.188  Bcast:172.24.159.255  Mask:255.255.255.128          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          RX packets:200502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000           RX bytes:116383128 (110.9 MiB)  TX bytes:84 (84.0 b)          Memory:fb980000-fba00000eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:67:D0:D3            inet addr:108.170.5.50  Bcast:108.170.5.55  Mask:255.255.255.248          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          RX packets:6871 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:6675 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000           RX bytes:595358 (581.4 KiB)  TX bytes:2617432 (2.4 MiB)          Memory:fb900000-fb980000eth1:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:67:D0:D3            inet addr:108.170.5.51  Bcast:108.170.5.55  Mask:255.255.255.248          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          Memory:fb900000-fb980000eth1:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:67:D0:D3            inet addr:108.170.5.52  Bcast:108.170.5.55  Mask:255.255.255.248          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          Memory:fb900000-fb980000eth1:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:67:D0:D3            inet addr:108.170.5.53  Bcast:108.170.5.55  Mask:255.255.255.248          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          Memory:fb900000-fb980000eth1:4    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:67:D0:D3            inet addr:108.170.5.54  Bcast:108.170.5.55  Mask:255.255.255.248          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          Memory:fb900000-fb980000lo        Link encap:Local Loopback            inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0           RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1**

```
DEVICE="eth1"BOOTPROTO="static"HWADDR="00:25:90:67:D0:D3"NM_CONTROLLED="yes"ONBOOT="yes"TYPE="Ethernet"UUID="1abe3d9d-66bc-4fdc-bf37-c89d3d3d33d2"IPADDR="108.170.5.50"NETMASK="255.255.255.248"GATEWAY="108.170.5.49"
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:4**

```
DEVICE="eth1:4"BOOTPROTO="static"IPADDR="108.170.5.54"NETMASK="255.255.255.248"ONBOOT="yes"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правильно ли пытаться сделать Bridge'ем лишь один из 5 IP ...

нет, надо именно создать бридж , а на него уже подвесить нужные вам IP. Покажите `brctl show`.